# Can you position a fixed element in the viewport vertically, but in the parent element horizonally?

Tags: html, css, css-position

```css
/* position */
.container {
    width: 40vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

/* style */
p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#body p {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#footer p {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="body">
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>this is the footer content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Same code is at https://jsfiddle.net/bxkgL9zs/4/ if you prefer)

as you can see, the sticky footer element:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

seems to be contained inside the container element:

```
.container {
    width: 40vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

since it isn't stuck all the way to the left of the screen like you would expect.

My question is, how can I make the footer the full with of the container, but still fixed to the bottom of the screen, like it is now?

I would have thought `right: auto` would do it, since `left: auto` (what it is now) seems to put it correctly in the container on the left.

Comment: Just add `left: 0` to `#footer`

Comment: Why did you rollback the edits to this question, @JakubMatczak?

Comment: @DanielBeck you removed JSFiddle link, which is still the most helpful thing here despite of your native SO snippet. JSFiddle is far more better to play with the code.

Comment: @JakubMatczak As you presumably know, code belongs on the site, not on external sites, because link rot is a thing that exists.  jsfiddle is not "better to play with the code", it's functionally identical to the internal snippet.  I'm reverting your rollback (but will restore the jsfiddle link as an alternative.)

Comment: left:0 and right:0 will do the need full else if you want equal widh as the container then change the left: 30vw and right:30vw.

Comment: As you know the container is 40vw, can you not just add that to your footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `position: fixed;`

> The element is removed from the normal flow of the document, without creating any space for the element in the outline of the page. It is positioned relative to  the container block  initial established by the viewport , except When one of Its ancestors have to  transform,  perspective, or  filter Property Set to something other than  none (see the  CSS Transforms Spec ), in Which case That ancestor behaves as the container containing block. (Note That there are inconsistencies With browser  perspective and  filter contributing to block container containing formation.) Its position is determined to end by the values of  top,  right,  bottom, and  left.
>   This value always creates a new  stacking context . In printed documents, the element is placed in the same position on  every page .

So that is why your `#footer` is being aligned at the bottom but not at the full left because the left position is by default relative to  the container block in your case `container`

If you want the footer go to full left just add

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;      //add this
}
```

If you want the `#footer` in the actual position but filling the entire container space just add

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40vw;    //add the same width of the container
}
```

To have better understanding of the positioning read this https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: great! `width: 40vw;` fixes is. I was about to say though, that sometimes I don't actually know the width of the container. but `width: inherit` seems to work

thank you

Comment: @user3493851 I'm glad to help you, remember if you want to align the content inside the footer just add `text-align: center;` to `#footer`

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 40vw;` to your footer, simple as that...

```css
/* position */
.container {
    width: 40vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40vw;
}

/* style */
p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#body p {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#footer p {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="body">
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>this is the footer content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't make the footer *the full width of the container*

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you clarify what is your end result?

Comment: Edited my answer, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `width: 40vw;` is what I needed yes, but sometimes I don't know the width of the container though, so I'm trying `width: inherit` seems to be the same so far
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the same width as the container and make the `p` inside it to be `inline-block` so you can easily center it:

```css
/* position */
.container {
    width: 40vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align:center;
    width: 40vw;
}

/* style */
p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#body p {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#footer p {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="body">
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>this is the footer content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```